# Looking for the smallest number in a map always prints 0

Tags: c++

I am writing a program to find the smallest number in a map but it is not working as expected. The expected result is 2 but it always prints 0.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> myMap = { {1, 3} , {2, 5}, {3, 22}, {4, 2} };
    int temp = myMap[0];
    for (int i = 1; i <= 4; ++i) {
        if (myMap[i] < temp) {
            temp = myMap[i];
        }
    }
    cout << "smallest number: " << temp << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Check the value of temp after `int temp = myMap[0];`. More generally: use a debugger

Answer (score 1):

In hindsight, the feature of `std::map` where a missing element is *inserted* into a `std::map` if not present (with the payload *value-initialised*; i.e. 0 in your case), such as your case with the statement

```
int temp = myMap[0]; // myMap[0] is value-initialised, i.e. is 0.
```

, was probably not a good idea. It also carries the drawback that the `[]` operator is not `const`.

However, from C++14 you can write simply

```
auto it = std::min_element(
    myMap.begin(),
    myMap.end(),
    [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return l.second < r.second; }
);
```

followed by

```
std::cout << "smallest number: " << it->second << std::endl;
```

to yield the value. Check of course that `it` is valid - in that way it will work on an empty container.

Comment: The feature is good, but it really should be a properly named function instead of the index-operator

Answer (score 0):

`myMap[0]` equals zero (because zero isn't in your map). Change the code to this

```
#include <limits>

int temp = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
```

This code assigns `temp` to be the maximum possible `int`. Any integer you find after that will be smaller and will update `temp`.

Answer (score 0):

Because myMap[0] is not a valid item in your map. Hence the value assigned is always 0.
Try with below code

```
int temp = myMap[1];
```